# Can't update data because Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to update data from a joined table called siswas and gurus then it show a error 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()'. My database have a relationship on mySQL not from laravel model so guru model and siswa model is blank. This is my update() code

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'id'=>'required',
            'nama'=> 'required',
            'alamat'=> 'required',
            'tempatLahir'=> 'required',
            'tanggalLahir'=> 'required',
            'namaBapak'=> 'required',
            'namaIbu'=> 'required',
            'noTelp'=> 'required',
            'kelas'=> 'required',

        ]);

        $siswas = DB::table('siswas')
        ->join('gurus','gurus.id','=','siswas.kelas')
        ->select('siswas.id','siswas.nama','gurus.guruKelas','siswas.status'
        ,'siswas.fotoSiswa','siswas.alamat','siswas.noTelp','siswas.tempatLahir'
        ,'siswas.tanggalLahir','siswas.namaBapak','siswas.namaIbu')
        ->where("siswas.id",$id)
        ->limit(1);
        $siswas->id = $request->input('id');
        $siswas->nama = $request->input('nama');
        $siswas->alamat = $request->input('alamat');
        $siswas->tempatLahir = $request->input('tempatLahir');
        $siswas->tanggalLahir = $request->input('tanggalLahir');
        $siswas->namaBapak = $request->input('namaBapak');
        $siswas->namaIbu = $request->input('namaIbu');
        $siswas->noTelp = $request->input('noTelp');
        $siswas->guruKelas = $request->input('kelas');
        $siswas->status = $request->input('status');
        if($request->hasFile('fotoSiswa')){
            //get filename with extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('fotoSiswa')->getClientOriginalName();
            //get just file name
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('fotoSiswa')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //upload Image
            $path = $request->file('fotoSiswa')->storeAs('public/fotoSiswa', $fileNameToStore);
            if ($request->hasFile('fotoSiswa')) 
            {
                Storage::delete('public/fotoSiswa/' . $gurus->fotoSiswa);

            }
            $siswas->fotoSiswa = $fileNameToStore;
        }
        $siswas->save();
        return redirect('/siswa')->with('success','Data siswa telah dirubah!');

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code actually has multiple errors.

The first thing I noticed is that your fetch query [is never executed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results). So you are setting properties of a query builder object with is not useful at all. You should add `->first()` to your query to get the first record from the database.

Next, you are not using [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent). using `DB::table('')` will return plain PHP objects. You cannot call `->save()` on a plain PHP object. You have to create an update query to update these in the database.

Comment: thanks! you are very helpful, i shouldn't use ->save() instead update(['nama' =>  $request->nama], ...)

Answer (score 0):

this fetches your record.

```
$siswas = DB::table('siswas')
        ->join('gurus','gurus.id','=','siswas.kelas')
        ->select('siswas.id','siswas.nama','gurus.guruKelas','siswas.status'
        ,'siswas.fotoSiswa','siswas.alamat','siswas.noTelp','siswas.tempatLahir'
        ,'siswas.tanggalLahir','siswas.namaBapak','siswas.namaIbu')
        ->where("siswas.id",$id)
        ->limit(1)
        ->first();
```

whatever thing you are trying to do with this, i dont know.

```
$siswas->id = $request->input('id');
        $siswas->nama = $request->input('nama');
        $siswas->alamat = $request->input('alamat');
        $siswas->tempatLahir = $request->input('tempatLahir');
        $siswas->tanggalLahir = $request->input('tanggalLahir');
        $siswas->namaBapak = $request->input('namaBapak');
        $siswas->namaIbu = $request->input('namaIbu');
        $siswas->noTelp = $request->input('noTelp');
        $siswas->guruKelas = $request->input('kelas');
        $siswas->status = $request->input('status');
```

and remember, this is query builder not eloquent so no need for `save()`

to do your update, you need to do something like this:

```
$id = $request->input('id');
        $nama = $request->input('nama');
        $alamat = $request->input('alamat');
        $tempatLahir = $request->input('tempatLahir');
        $tanggalLahir = $request->input('tanggalLahir');
        $namaBapak = $request->input('namaBapak');
        $namaIbu = $request->input('namaIbu');
        $noTelp = $request->input('noTelp');
        $guruKelas = $request->input('kelas');
        $status = $request->input('status');

DB::table('siswas')
    ->join('gurus','gurus.id','=','siswas.kelas')
    ->where('id',$id)
    ->update(['name'=>$nama,'alamat'=>$alamat,'tempatLahir '=>$tempatLahir,...]);
```

i dont think you need this `public function update(Request $request, $id)` `$id` parameter here, since you are already getting it from the `$id=$request->input(id)`
it should just be like this `public function update(Request $request)`